# Turn on and off the subtitle in flutter chewie player

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player, subtitle

I am doing a flutter app to play video using flutter chewie player. I have given subtitle wrapper to display subtitle from a url in it. but i want to create a button in video playing screen to turn on and off the subtitle.Can anyone help on how to turn on and off the subtitle in subtitle wrapper.
my subtitle wrapper code is as below:

```
 SubTitleWrapper(
 videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
 subtitleController: SubtitleController(
subtitleUrl:subtitle url,
showSubtitles: true),
videoChild: Chewie(controller: chewieController, ), ),
```

it will be help full if there is any example for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an extra widget as data to the chewie controller's `additionalOptions` parameter and set an action, as per your requirement toggle subtitle, based on the tap of the widget.

**Steps:**

*First, create a subtitle controller so that we can toggle subtitle on user's click:*

```
final _subtitleController = SubtitleController(
    subtitleUrl:subtitle url,
    showSubtitles: true);
```

*Now pass the subtitle widget as additional data to the chewie controller:*

```
final chewieController = ChewieController(
  additionalOptions: (context) {
  return <OptionItem>[
    OptionItem(
      onTap: () => _subtitleController.showSubtitles = !_subtitleController.showSubtitles,
      iconData: Icons.subtitles,
      title: 'Toggle Subtitle',
    )
  ];
},
 // ...other parameters
);
```

Now, make a change to your subtitle wrapper as:

```
SubTitleWrapper(
   subtitleController: _subtitleController
   ... other parameters
)
```

Comment: PS: I haven't checked this, if this doesn't work please let me know since I can't check as I am in a bit of hurry, don't mind pls xS

Comment: can this be done in CupertinoControls.. as in material controls there is no forward and backward button. i dont know how to implement forward and backward button in material controls

Comment: You can try out.

Comment: _subtitleController.showSubtitles this line is showing error as "'showSubtitles' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'showSubtitles' non-final."